# can i restrict behaviour of polymorphism?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism, nodes

So i'm trying to implement a binary search tree and avl tree. Each of these classes using different but similar types of nodes. The classes for nodes look like this:

```
class node
{
protected:
    int key;
    node* parent, * left, * right;
public:
    node(int key, node* parent = nullptr) :key(key), parent(parent), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
    ~node() {}
};
```

---

```
class avl_node : public node
{
private:
    int height;
public:
    avl_node(int key, int height, avl_node* parent = nullptr) :node(key, parent), height(height) {}
    ~avl_node() {}
};
```

This mostly works. Any `node` can have connexions with any other `node`, and any `avl_node` with any other `avl_node`. The issue that I think of is that a `node` could technically have a parent or children `avl_node` because of polymorphism, and I wouldn't want that to happen. Although I can avoid that by being careful, i wouldn't want it to be possible at all. Is there a way?
*p.s.* I want to keep the classes related

Comment: If you don't want polymorphism, why using sub-classing then? Could you please precise what what's wrong with your code? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: If you want type-safe implementation of containers, you should look into templates, not polymorphism - that's exactly why they were invented. Otherwise, you would be fighting a core feature of the language.

Comment: You can't both keep the classes related and avoid polymorphism. Why do you want to keep them related?

Comment: @molbdnilo to avoid duplicated code

Comment: @stack_overflow_nickname You don't need the classes to be related for that.

Answer (score 1):

If it's enough, you could explicitly delete the version of constructor that would take an `avl_node*`

```
class node
{
protected:
    int key;
    node* parent, * left, * right;
public:
    node(int key, node* parent = nullptr) :key(key), parent(parent), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
    node(int, avl_node*) = delete;
    ~node() {}
};
```

Of course, this solution is not foolproof. If you brought an `avl_node` hidden behind a `node` pointer, the compiler wouldn't be able to tell (and since polymorphism is mainly dynamic, you would only be protected in this specific case where you attempt to assign the pointer directly)

This would compile.

```
avl_node myavl;
node n(0, static_cast<node*>(&myavl));
```

You could try dynamic-casting in the `node` constructor to tell if it's an `avl_node` being passed (your nodes would need a vtable for that), but that would make it impossible to call the constructor like that from the `avl_node` constructor.

Another option would be making a separate constructor intended specifically for the subclass

```
class node
{
protected:
    int key;
    node* parent, * left, * right;
    node(int key, avl_node* parent) : key(key), parent(parent), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
public:
    node(int key, node* parent = nullptr) :key(key), parent(parent), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) { /* do something to not allow avl_node* to be passed */ }
    ~node() {}
};
```

Comment: i've got an issue here. Since `avl_node` is derived from `node`, inside 'node' class,  `avl_node` is not even defined. I tried to include the following line you suggested `node(int, avl_node*) = delete;` and i got this error : *syntax error: identifier 'avl_node'*

Comment: Just forward-declare what you need (or `node(int, class avl_node*)` with the `class` keyword already counts as declaration)

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of polymorphism *and* avoid code duplication by using a class template for the base, and members that depend on the template argument.

Example:

```
template<typename T>
class node
{
protected:
    int key;
    node* parent, * left, * right;  // Note: these are actually 'node<T>'.
public:
    node(int key, node* parent = nullptr) 
        : key(key), parent(parent), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
    void set_parent(node* p) { parent = p; }
};

class avl_node : public node<avl_node>
{
private:
    int height;
public:
    avl_node(int key, int height, avl_node* parent = nullptr) 
        : node(key, parent), height(height) {}
};

class silly_node : public node<silly_node>
{
public:
    silly_node() : node(0) {} 
};

int main()
{
    // Fine
    avl_node an(0, 1);
    // Fine
    avl_node bn(0, 1, &an);
    // Also fine
    bn.set_parent(&an);
    // Fine
    silly_node sn;
    // Compilation error
    avl_node cn(0, 1, &sn);
    // Also compilation error
    bn.set_parent(&sn);
}
```

Comment: why is `node` actually `node<T>`? How does that work? Also, it's not clear to me how would I create an instance of the `node` class.

Comment: Inside a template, the template name itself refers to the current instantiation. And that you can't create `node` instances is the entire point; `node` instantiations are unrelated but inherit the code from the instantiation of the base template.

Comment: So the idea would be to use `silly_node` in my `binary_search_tree` class and `avl_node` in my `avl_tree` class?

Comment: `silly_node` is just an example to illustrate the compilation error. As its name suggests, it is silly and should not be used for anything. The idea is to create one instantiation for each type of tree - for instance `class binary_search_node : public node<binary_search_node> ...`.

Comment: I ran into one more issue here. So i made a `binary_search_tree` class which has a member `root` which is of type `node*`. In a method i'm trying to do `root=root->left`, but i get the following error: _a value of type `t_node<node>*` cannot be assigned to an entity of type `node*`_. P.s. `t_node` is the template class and `node` is a class derived from it